# to copy a line from the Table2 into the Table1 each time a value for the key of 2 columns is not found (some kind of a merge by criteria)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Could you please help me to figure out how to do this in **power query**

I have two tables, for instance:

Table1-Database

| Store | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Store1 | Product A |
| Store1 | Product B |
| Store2 | Product A |
| Store2 | Product B |

...etc

Table2 - Product Master Table

| Product |
| --- |
| Product A |
| Product B |
| Product X |
| Product Z |

What I need to achieve: each time a Product is not found in a given Store it is being added; the new merged table to look like this:

| Store | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Store1 | Product A |
| Store1 | Product B |
| Store1 | Product X |
| Store1 | Product Z |
| Store2 | Product A |
| Store2 | Product B |
| Store2 | Product X |
| Store2 | Product Z |

I tried to use full outer joint merge but it simply add missing product in the bottom of the merged table (i.e. 2 entries at the bottom of the merged table)

Comment: Consider using `CROSSJOIN` dax function. It should be something like `CROSSJOIN(VALUES('Table1'[Store]),Table2)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

- right click Store column and remove duplicates
- right click Product column and remove
- add column ,custom column, with formula =OtherTableName
- expand that column into new rows using arrows atop the new column

sample full code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source, {"Store"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"Product"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Product", each Table3),
#"Expanded Product" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Product", {"Product"}, {"Product"})
in  #"Expanded Product"
```